# Why isn't KeyRemap4MacBook's "PageUp/PageDown to Left/Right (only in iPhoto)" setting working?

Tags: keyboard, remote-control, keybindings

I have "PageUp/PageDown to Left/Right (only in iPhoto)" checked in [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) (version 7.5.0):
[image]
And I've confirmed that my (non-Kensington) wireless USB gadget shows a PageDown and PageUp in KeyDump when I press the next slide and previous slide buttons:

```
eventType:keyDown   code:0x79   name:PageDown   flags:Fn    misc:characters:
eventType:keyUp code:0x79   name:PageDown   flags:Fn    misc:characters:
eventType:keyDown   code:0x74   name:PageUp flags:Fn    misc:characters:
eventType:keyUp code:0x74   name:PageUp flags:Fn    misc:characters:
```

But when I put iPhoto (version 9.2.1) in slideshow mode, the right and left arrow keys change the photo, but the buttons on my gadget don't work.

Any ideas why this isn't working? I thought perhaps KeyRemap4MacBook is remapping my MacBook Air's internal keyboard, but not the external USB keyboard that my gadget is pretending to be.  But fn-Down-Arrow and fn-Up-Arrow (which show as PageDown and PageUp in KeyDump) also don't work in iPhoto.

(My MBA is running OS X 10.7.2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question on the [KeyRemap4MacBook Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/keyremap4macbook/browse_thread/thread/970266efc1a4b3f5), and got a reply from Takayama Fumihiko, the creator of KeyRemap4MacBook.  He had me send him the vendor ID and product ID for the device, and sent me back a private.xml file with a new setting that worked.  (The pre-defined "PageUp/PageDown to Left/Right (only in iPhoto)" setting only works with the vendor ID and product ID for the Kensington K33374 USB remote.)

Here's the private.xml file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>

  <devicevendordef>
    <vendorname>Tenx_Technology_Inc</vendorname>
    <vendorid>0x1130</vendorid>
  </devicevendordef>

  <deviceproductdef>
    <productname>Tenx_wireless_USB_gadget</productname>
    <productid>0x6604</productid>
  </deviceproductdef>

  <item>
    <name>PageUp/PageDown to Left/Right (only in iPhoto)</name>
    <appendix>(This is effective only with "Tenx_wireless_USB_gadget")</appendix>
    <identifier>private.pageupdown2leftright_iphoto</identifier>
    <only>IPHOTO</only>
    <device_only>DeviceVendor::Tenx_Technology_Inc,DeviceProduct::Tenx_wireless_USB_gadget</device_only>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- FROMKEYCODE_PAGEUP,   KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT</autogen>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- FROMKEYCODE_PAGEDOWN, KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT</autogen>
  </item>

</root>
```

See the ["How to add new settings" section](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html#t3) in the KeyRemap4MacBook documentation for instructions on what to do with the private.xml file (except replace the file instead of editing the original one with a text editor).